# Can we tweak Python Elasticsearch connection parameters when fetching indices

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Hope someone can comment with similar experience and possible solutions with Python Elasticsearch client (http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

```
>>> from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
>>> import requests 
>>> import json
>>> es = Elasticsearch(['http://es-service:9200'],sniff_on_start=True, sniff_timeout=300)
>>> es.indices.get_alias("*")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/user/tester/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/user/tester/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/indices.py", line 416, in get_alias
    '_alias', name), params=params)
  File "/user/tester/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 329, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/user/tester/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 105, in perform_request
    raise ConnectionError('N/A', str(e), e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError((<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb46baa8750>, u'Connection to 192.168.5.245 timed out. (connect timeout=10)')) caused by: ConnectTimeoutError((<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb46baa8750>, u'Connection to 192.168.5.245 timed out. (connect timeout=10)'))

[root@myhost ~]# nslookup es-service
Server:         172.16.50.150
Address:        172.16.50.150#53

Name:   es-service.somedomain.com
Address: 10.90.5.245
```

The problem is, Elasticsearch in es-service is configured to use
192.168.5.245 as transport address. That is a different interface from 10.90.5.245 and is not meant to be reachable from outside.

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://es-service:9200/_nodes/_all/clear.HTTP?pretty')
>>> print(r.text)
{
  "cluster_name" : "super-es",
  "nodes" : {
    "oOabsR4dSzC7zxNVnX0l5g" : {
      "name" : "Bounty Hunter",
      "transport_address" : "192.168.5.245:9300",
      "host" : "192.168.5.245",
      "ip" : "192.168.5.245",
      "version" : "2.4.1",
      "build" : "c67dc32",
      "http_address" : "192.168.5.245:9200"
    },
    "unCQYE3jRBSMiMxs9DRG0A" : {
      "name" : "Jack Flag",
      "transport_address" : "192.168.5.220:9300",
      "host" : "192.168.5.220",
      "ip" : "192.168.5.220",
      "version" : "2.4.1",
      "build" : "c67dc32",
      "http_address" : "192.168.5.220:9200"
    }
  }
}
```

Question: Is there a way to tell Python or the Elasticsearch module to use the IP which i used as host, and not the transport IP it received from es-service?

Comments and suggestions are as welcome.

Comment: Can't understand well the problem, why you can't simply use another endpoint e.g. es_2 = Elasticsearch(['http://10.90.5.245:9200'],sniff_on_start=True, sniff_timeout=300) ?

Comment: This will result in the same situation when trying to fetch indices and other stuff from ES DB. When creating the object (es_2), Python fetches the data using URL "http://es-service:9200/_nodes/_all/clear.HTTP?pretty". Now for indices (es_2.indices.get_alias("*") ), Python will use the transport address which it got in above response. This will fail as transport address is different from 10.90.5.245.